# How to start mobile keyboard default

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I use `Delphi XE7 FireMonkey`, i need the Android virtual keyboard to start default and not the GBoard keyboard

Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user gets to specify the keyboard.  There's no way to be sure the "default" keyboard (by the way, there is no default keyboard installed on all Android devices) is even installed.  There are ways to specify a specific keyboard, but they should only be used if you're bundling a keyboard inside your own app.  Otherwise honor the user's choice of input method.

This is an accessibility issue as well.  People with physical disabilities like Parkinson's, blindness, etc frequently use specialized keyboards.  You should not take that ability from them.